# In Jquery, how can I identify which div has active and then use same ID for a different div's visibility

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to find answer but nothing so far.

The code I'm working on doesn't seem right at all, but it's where I've gotten so far.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.charbox').find(".active").attr('id');
    var des = $('charbox.active').attr('id');
    $('.charsum.des').css("visibility", 'visible');
```

I want the jquery to identify which charbox div ID has the active attribute.
And once it finds it, it'll use the ID, which is the same as as the ones in infobox to run a code to change the visibility of the matching ID to visible.

All in all, I wanted to make active buttons that display the different texts that match their button's ID in another div. I click a character button and inside the separate div, it shows the text.

The CSS I have is:

```
 infobox #dva {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: `which is the same as as the ones in infobox` wont work because **ID should be unique** `use class or add data attribute`

Answer (score 0):

best way to doing this is to use data attribute

say in html

```
<div class="charbox active" data-id="SOME_ID"></div>
```

in js

```
var getId = $('.charbox.active').data('id'); // or .attr('data-id');
```

// then use it like

```
$('#'+getId)  // in this case this mean #SOME_ID
```